# How to install Google Earth on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, installation, google-earth

I found a [tutorial](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/06/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1104.html), but it explicitly notes that it is for 11.04.  Based on your own experience, is it also applicable to 11.10?

Based on your own experience, does it work to just download and install the .deb file from the [official page](http://www.google.com/earth/index.html)?

Comment: This isn't worth an entire answer, so I'll just put it here. The normal .deb file has always worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install it from [this](http://www.google.com/intl/en/earth/download/ge/agree.html) website. Remember that Google Earth is a "windows ported" application, so it have some bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the deb found on the official page is sufficient, I just checked.

But some very precise functionalities may not function well, if I remember. Something like opening a location in Google Maps in your browser may not work. Google is working on it.

According to the [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/google-earth-62-released-with-new-way.html) website, you may also need to install the [msttcorefonts](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/msttcorefonts) package to get better font rendering.